# Unknown property 'Converter' for type ... in my custom Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am unable to get a custom binding working with a converter, getting this when building the project:

> Error 2   Unknown property 'Converter' for type 'MS.Internal.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser+UnknownMarkupExtension' encountered while parsing a Markup Extension.

The error points to this code:

```
<KeyBinding 
        Key="{helper:KeyboardShortcut InsertTargetToSource, Converter={StaticResource KeyGestureConverterKey},ConverterParameter=Key}" 
        Modifiers="{helper:KeyboardShortcut InsertTargetToSource, Converter={StaticResource KeyGestureConverterKey},ConverterParameter=Modifiers}" 
        Command="{Binding CopyToTargetCommand}"/>
```

KeyboardShortCut is a binding from a Settings file :

```
public class KeyboardShortcutExtension : Binding
{
    public KeyboardShortcutExtension()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public KeyboardShortcutExtension(string path)
        : base(path)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        this.Source = TI.Shortcuts.Default;
        this.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    }

}
```

And the converter converts from string (like "Ctrl+Shift+X") to Key and Modifiers:

```
private KeyGestureConverter mConverter = new KeyGestureConverter();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var text = value.ToString();
        var gesture = mConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(text) as KeyGesture;
        if (parameter == "Key")
        {
            return gesture.Key;
        }
        if (parameter == "Modifiers")
        {
            return gesture.Modifiers;
        }
        return gesture;
    }
```

Is there something I am missing? Or should I take a different approach when trying to bind from a string in Settings file to a KeyBinding?

EDIT:

Using the following code, everything works fine, but the code is not readable. Is there a way of generating this automatically, so in my markup I would write e.g. just

```
<MyKeyBinding Value="CopyToTargetCommand"/>
```

and it would generate the rest?

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding CopyToTargetCommand}">
        <KeyBinding.Key>
            <helper:KeyboardShortcut Path="InsertTargetToSource" ConverterParameter="Key">
                <helper:KeyboardShortcut.Converter>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="KeyGestureConverterKey"/>
                </helper:KeyboardShortcut.Converter>
            </helper:KeyboardShortcut>
        </KeyBinding.Key>
        <KeyBinding.Modifiers>
            <helper:KeyboardShortcut Path="InsertTargetToSource" ConverterParameter="Modifiers">
                <helper:KeyboardShortcut.Converter>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="KeyGestureConverterKey"/>
                </helper:KeyboardShortcut.Converter>
            </helper:KeyboardShortcut>
        </KeyBinding.Modifiers>
    </KeyBinding>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11785248/389966

Comment: If it is, what should help me? I read the links in there and nothing is applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CustomizableKeyBinding : KeyBinding
{
    public CustomizableKeyBinding()
        : base()
    {
    }

    StringToKeyGestureConverter converter = new StringToKeyGestureConverter();

    public string Description
    {
        set
        {
            InitBindings(value);
        }
    }

    private void InitBindings(string value)
    {
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, KeyBinding.KeyProperty, new KeyboardShortcutExtension(value) { Converter = converter, ConverterParameter = "Key" });
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, KeyBinding.ModifiersProperty, new KeyboardShortcutExtension(value) { Converter = converter, ConverterParameter = "Modifiers" });
    }
}
```

Adn then in XAML:

```
 <helper:CustomizableKeyBinding Command="{Binding CopyToTargetCommand}" Description="..."/>
```