# Unknown property 'Converter' for type 'MS.Internal.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser+UnknownMarkupExtension' encountered while parsing a Markup Extension

Tags: c#, converters

I am binding to an ObservableCollection called ScaleFactor to a ComboBox. The value of the ObservableCollection are simply 1, 2, 4 and 8. I want to use an IValueConverter to change these values to x1, x2, x4 and x8.

My MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TimeLineCanvas.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:timeline="clr-namespace:TimeLineCanvas.UserControls"
        xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:TimeLineCanvas.Helpers"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <helper:ZoomConverter x:Key="ZoomConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <StackPanel>    
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SSS}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource ZoomConverter}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace TimeLineCanvas
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        #region Constructors

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SSS = new ObservableCollection<int>();
            SSS.Add(1);
            SSS.Add(2);
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        #endregion    

        public ObservableCollection<int> SSS { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

And the converter

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace TimeLineCanvas.Helpers
{
    public class ZoomConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return "x" + value.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why this is, I'm not using MarkupExtensions so I don't think [this link helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785248/error-when-binding-using-markup-extensions-unknown-property-encountered-while-p). Can any one shed any light?

Comment: You are binding to `ScaleFactor` which would imply that's singular. Is that of type IEnumerable?

Comment: I updated my comment, but I am using  public ObservableCollection<int> ScaleFactor { get; set; } - there are always 4 items

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you have. Try doing ... `{Binding ., Converter` (dot then a comma)

Comment: @gleng, thank you, but alas, the same issue persists.

Comment: Bah, only other thing I could possible see being wrong is the converter isn't defined in scope of the ComboBox (it's hard to tell with the alignment of the code you've posted). Might want to define it in the <ComboBox.Resources> and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @gleng, I have updated my code, the issue is persisting in both my UserControl and my MainWindow. As such, I have removed as much code as I can. The code above creates the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use a comma after `Binding`. This way you call the empty constructor on the `Binding` object.

```
{Binding, Converter={StaticResource ZoomConverter}}
```

should be

```
{Binding Converter={StaticResource ZoomConverter}}
```

Comment: And just that simple! Thank you for your help.